# React Next JS : How to decide when to get query parameters server-side vs client-side?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, next-router

I am new to `NextJS`, can someone explain to me the use case when I need to get the URL `query parameters` from `server-side` or `client side` ? or `both`?

I am using `ssr` (Server Side Rendering) because `SEO` is important to me, and I have a `../search?book_name=something&type=etc` page that have multiple `filters` that will add `query parameters` to the exising `url` when clicked

Should I get the `query parameters` `server side`? or `client side`? or `both`?

Comment: It actually depends on your requirement. If you are fetching some data in getServerSideProps or in getInitialProps (in server) then you may want to use them.

Comment: is there any difference between the two? how will SEO be impacted by this?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the query parameters from server-side or client side"? Can you show a concrete example (with code) of what you're trying to achieve?